# how to post special character and symbol using php

Tags: php, string

I am new one in php.I was just create a form for sending special character and symbol  using .I got for get the text

```
<form name='form1' method='post' action='s.php'>
<textarea name='ask' id='ask' style=' resize:none ; border: #093; height:250px;     width:350px'></textarea><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</form>
```

this is form  and s.php is

```
<?php
 $ask=$_POST['ask'];
 echo $ask;
?>
```

inputed value

```
  #include<iostream.h>
```

but i got only

**#include**
why did i got output like this ? and any method to get full text . Please help me anyone

Answer (score 4):

Right click and view the page source.  The `<iostream.h>` is being interpreted as an HTML tag by your browser.

Passing the value through [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) will make it work as expected:

```
$ask = $_POST['ask'];
echo htmlentities($ask);
```